# Include a Null or $0 when data does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sum, sql-server-2014

The pa.fdpayadjamount table has a few different categories (deposit, payment etc.) What I want to do is sum all the deposits and where a deposit does not exist, make the amount automatically input a $0 or null. Can someone please assist me with this? Thanks!

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, Cast(iv.fdinnetdeposit/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) AS [Deposit Required]
, Cast(Sum(pa.fdpayadjamount)/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) AS Deposit
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbinsverification') AS iv
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
ON iv.fdcase = ca.id
JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ar.tbpayadjmaster') AS pa
ON pa.fdpatient = pt.id
WHERE iv.fdinnetdeposit is not Null AND iv.fdinnetdeposit <> '0' AND ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed' AND pa.fdledgercodetype = 'Deposit'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, iv.fdinnetdeposit, pt.fdmedrecnum
```

Comment: Do you have a table with the payment categories ?. Because then you would only need to do your SELECT from that table of categories, and LEFT JOIN it with the payments and rest of your query. When a category is empty its payments will appear as Null.

Comment: There is a table that defines the payment categories but I cannot seem to figure it out how to write it in the query. I am still fairly new to SQL. Can you tell me where to write it and what to eliminate from the above statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually what resolved the issue for myself:

```
, Sum(Case When pa.fddescription = 'Deposit' Then Cast(pa.fdpayadjamount/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) Else 0 END) AS Deposit
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just need to add the ISNULL() function on the fifth line like so.

```
, Cast(ISNULL(Sum(pa.fdpayadjamount),0)/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) AS Deposit
```

Comment: Maybe better to move the ISNULL inside: Cast(Sum(ISNULL(pa.fdpayadjamount,0)/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) AS Deposit

Comment: @Chris - The results did not reflect any Null's.

Comment: Sorry, this should work - Cast(
 Sum(
  ISNULL(pa.fdpayadjamount,0)
  )/100.0 as decimal(10,2)
 )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code where you are doing the sum.

isnull(Cast(Sum(pa.fdpayadjamount)/100.0 as decimal(10,2)),0) AS Deposit

Comment: This still did not return any null results for deposits. I wonder if I have to look elsewhere in my query for any issues!?